# Div to stretch to fit contents. Overflow: auto; does not work

Tags: html, css

I've created a long scrolling website composed of different sections which fill up the whole screen.   One Section contains some pretty lengthy text but the top and bottom parts of the text are cut off.  Basically my div won't stretch all the way to accommodate the text.  I would like my div **to be able** to stretch to at least 200% down.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc7Uu/905/)

I've tried

```
overflow:auto;
min-height:100%;
```

This is what it looks like, as you can see at the bottom...the text is cut off.

[image]

If I remove Position: absolute;  The whole text moves to the left and the bottom text is still cut off.

[image]
This is part of my html:

```
<section id="slide-15" class="homeSlide">


 <div class="bcg">
       <div class="hsContainer">


       <h1>CV GUIDE</h1>
       <br>

         <h2>
           //lengthy text goes here
           //lengthy text goes here
           //lengthy text goes here
         </h2>

      </div>
</div>

</section>
```

and part of style.css

```
#slide-15 .bcg {
/*position: relative;*/
background-color: #1C1C1C;
min-height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
/*padding:150px;*/
}

slide-15 .hsContent {
        position: relative;
}

slide-15 .hscontainer {

       width-100%
       min-height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
       /* position:relative;*/
}


#slide-15 h1 {
                margin: 70px;
                color: #ffffff;
                font-size: 30px;
                line-height: 20px;
                 position: relative;
                 text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}


#slide-15 h2 {
                 color: #ffffff;
                 font-size: 14px;
                 line-height: 150%;
                 position: absolute;
                 line-spacing: 1px;
                 text-align: justify;
                 width: 700px;
                 top: 50%;
                 left: 50%;
                 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
           }
```

Comment: Add a fiddle man. @SO make fiddle is must for css qs.

Comment: That is not even the needed CSS to get the same issue. Make a JSFIDDLE

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pc7Uu/905/

Answer (score 0):

with `position:absolute` it gets cut out of the workflow ,so you need to remove it with you want the parent div to adjust to height;

also set it to `display:inline-block` ,

check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/pc7Uu/907/)

---

You've got a lot of syntax errors in CSS,

I cleaned it up a little here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/pc7Uu/908/)

Comment: That' doesn't work for me.  Removing position: absolute removes the positioning of the text(moves it to the left) Which I don't want.

The text is still cut off.

Comment: Maioman is right, the `position: absolute` is the problem. Can you describe or make a sketch of what you want it to look like?

Comment: Ok, I'll do a screenshot of the Page then edit the above.  Thanks.

EDIT: have a look above.

Comment: if you want to leave space on left and right of your inline-block use `padding-left` & `padding-right` properties

Comment: Thanks.  I tried your recommendations but the whole text has moved to the left and the top is visible but bottom is still cut off.

Comment: the fiddle works ... if you want post link to live site

Comment: It's hosted on my private server.  I'll screenshot what it looks like now.

Comment: you can still move position:relative elements using top: and left properties;to avoid bottom cut-off use padding-bottom;

Comment: Your fiddle works but when I apply it to my site...the bottom is even more cut off.  Thanks very much for your help though.

Comment: sorry can't help you more

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a class in css like this:

```
.test {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

and apply it to your h2:

```
<h2 class="test">
     //lengthy text goes here
     //lengthy text goes here
     //lengthy text goes here
</h2>
```